# Loosing margin with javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why when I add the same html code with javascript jquery I loose margin ?
Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3md9S/) and you will understand me.

**jQuery**

```
 function addphone() {
$( "#phonedetails" ).append( '<div  >' +
    '<label>phone :</label>' +
    '<input type="text" /> '   +  
    '<input type="button" onclick="addphone()"/>'    +                       
    '</div>');  

 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="phonedetails">
    <div>
        <label>phone :</label>
        <input type="text" />     
        <input type="button" onclick="addphone();"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need space after phone <label>phone : </label>

Comment: Your label is useless. It isn't associated with the input. Add a `for` attribute or put the `input` inside the `label`.

Comment: Some reason I read the title of this and expected to discover a question about losing a profit margin due to the use of jQuery and JavaScript. That would've actually been interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't a margin, it is a space (i.e. what you get when you press the space bar) between the `label` and the `input`. It is missing in the code generated from JS.

Change:

```
'<label>phone :</label>' +
```

To:

```
'<label>phone :</label> ' +
                  //   ^ space here
```

Comment: thanks @Quentin it works now but why we have to add this space ?

Comment: so that there is a space between the label and the input, for the same reason that you would type `cats and dogs` and not `catsanddogs`.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't losing margins, you're losing whitespace:

http://jsfiddle.net/3md9S/2/

```
$( "#phonedetails" ).append( '<div  >' +
        '<label>phone :</label> ' + // SINGLE SPACE ADDED HERE
        '<input type="text" /> '   +  
        '<input type="button" onclick="addphone()"/>'    +                       
        '</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

That is just a white space in your html.

Also you don't have to write html again to append , you can clone it -

```
$( "#phonedetails" ).append($('#phonedetails div').eq(0).clone());
```

Demo `-->`  http://jsfiddle.net/3md9S/7/

Comment: thanks i have to write html again because i have to do some treatment with jquery first ;) but thanks for clone function.